# How does snakemake --show-failed-logs works

Tags: snakemake

I want to use snakemake with the `--show-failed-logs` parameter but not sure how it works or what to expect.

For example (not a working example I just typed and copied some code parts, if necessary I can create a working example)

My command is:

```
snakemake -s Snakefile_test.smk --configfile test.yml -j 4 --restart-times 2 --show-failed-logs
```

In Snakefile_test.smk I have a rule:

```
rule testrule:
    input:
        R1_trimmed = rules.trim.output.R1_trimmed,
        R2_trimmed = rules.trim.output.R2_trimmed
    output:
        plot_R1 = output+"/{sample}/figures/{sample}_R1_plot.png",
        plot_R2 = output+"/{sample}/figures/{sample}_R2_plot.png",
    log:
        testrule_log = output+"/{sample}/logs/plot_log.txt"
    run:
        shell("python scripts/createplot.py -r1_trimmed {input.R1_trimmed} -r2_trimmed {input.R2_trimmed} -plot_r1 {output.plot_R1} -plot_r2 {output.plot_R2} -log {log.testrule_log}")
```

In createplot.py to test I have something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(filename=args.log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
    logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
    #to add some content to the log file
    try:
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        logger.error(err)
    main()
    #to let the script crash
    a = 1/0
```

Because obviously createplot.py will crash the pipeline I expected that snakemake would print the contents of `testrule_log` to the screen. But that is not the case. I am using version 5.25.0

EDIT:

I am familiar with

```
    script:
        "scripts/createplot.py"
```

But need to use shell in this case. If that causes the problem let me know.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is.. It should be easy enough to try what it does right? According to the [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html) it does "Automatically display logs of failed jobs". My guess would be that at the end of a run, if any rule(s) failed, it prints what is in the log of the failed rules.

Comment: I understand your comment. I am also expecting that at the of a run the log of the failed rule will be printed because that is in the docs but that is not happening. The log is not printed, but I do see the error in the log file.